# How to handle error in a recursive procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to handle error in a recursive procedure? I'm using SQL Server 2012.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]
    @i INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION [T]
    BEGIN TRY

        PRINT @i

        IF @i = 10
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRANSACTION [T]
            RETURN;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @i = @i + 1;
            EXEC DBO.TEST @i;
        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION [T]

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [T]
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    END CATCH  
    
END
```

This is only a example, because I'm not authorized to post original code.

Comment: What error would that be? Can you post the stored procedure so we can actually help.

Comment: I'm confuse in what location of commit, and if SQL have a variable to check the recursivity level.

Comment: This is pure, unadulterated evil. T-SQL is a terrible programming language on its best days; using it to implement recursion and mixing that up with transactions is asking for trouble. In the example you posted, `@i` will indicate the level of recursion and should be helpful. If you don't have such a variable, you could use a row stored in a temp table. There is no way in T-SQL to access something like the stack trace (although I'd love to be proven wrong on this); you could use a profiler trace or extended events to track the calls outside the procedure, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]
    @i INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE @InNestedTransaction BIT;

    BEGIN TRY

        IF (@@TRANCOUNT = 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @InNestedTransaction = 0;
            BEGIN TRAN; -- only start a transaction if not already in one
        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @InNestedTransaction = 1;
        END;

        /*********************************************/
        PRINT @i

        IF @i = 8
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ForceError INT;
            --set @ForceError = 1/0; -- uncomment this line to force error.
        END
        IF @i = 10
        BEGIN
            RETURN;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @i = @i + 1;
            EXEC DBO.TEST @i;
        END
        /*********************************************/

        IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0 AND @InNestedTransaction = 0)
        BEGIN
           COMMIT;
        END;

    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0 AND @InNestedTransaction = 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
            SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            THROW;
        END

    END CATCH

END
```